# How to update the value of primary key?

Tags: sqlite

Suppose I have a table in Sqlite:

MySingleRowtable:

```
+--------------+
|  someHeader  |       <-----pk
+--------------+
|     aa       |
+--------------+
```

How to update the value of primary key?

I tried like:

```
UPDATE MySingleRowtable
SET 'someHeader' = 'bb'
WHERE 'someHeader'='aa';
```

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: Why you want to Change the Primary key?

Comment: @Jens I want to give the user this option in my app

Comment: @MilvNutt That makes no sence. Primary key should be a technical value which is not visible to the user. Also if you Change the pk of a table which is a fk in an other table you run in probles

Comment: @Jens I only need it to be uniqe that's it, but In my app I need to give the user that option

Comment: @MilvNutt than use a unique index. However what is the Problem with your query

Comment: @Jens Ok I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works :-

```
DELETE FROM MySingleRowTable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MySingleRowTable (someHeader PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO MySingleRowTable VALUES('aa');
SELECT * FROM MySingleRowTable;
UPDATE MySingleRowTable SET someHeader = 'bb' WHERE someHeader = 'aa';
SELECT * FROM MySingleRowTable;
```

[image]

However, you have :-

```
DELETE FROM MySingleRowTable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MySingleRowTable (someHeader PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO MySingleRowTable VALUES('aa');
SELECT * FROM MySingleRowTable;
UPDATE MySingleRowTable SET 'someHeader' = 'bb' WHERE 'someHeader' = 'aa';
SELECT * FROM MySingleRowTable;
```

[image]

That is you have the column names in single quotes so you are effectively saying

- UPDATE only when **someHeader** (the text) is **aa** it never will be.

As opposed to saying

- UPDATE only when the contents of the **column someHeader** has the value **aa**.